# R plotly, change ticks to italic

Tags: r, plotly

I`m a begginer with R, I try to use it to plot simple bar charts. The idea is to take acreage values of various soil types present in a given area, calculate percentage share of each and plot it as vertical bars. Everything is working fine expect I cant seem to find a way to change yaxis ticks labels to italic, which is a common practice while naming them. Below I present the code so far.

[image: plot]

I cant seem to find proper argument to use that would change tickfont to italic, I have tried `font.main = 3` , `face = 'italic'` and `font = 3` and none seem to have any effect. I know that my list `f3` presented below has an effect on the graph as modyfing size of ticks text, just that nothing seems to work to make it italic.

```
f3 <- list(family = "Arial, sans-serif", size =10, color = "black", font = 3)
b <- list(title = "Soil grouping", titlefont = f2, tickfont = f3)
p <- plot_ly(x,  y = ~Soil, x = ~pro, type = 'bar', orientation = "h") %>% layout(xaxis = a, yaxis = b)
```

I expect to obtain similar graph to the one linked, just with soil names in italic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly this is not available with a default argument. But plot_ly does give us the chance to use HTML code for the labels/ticks. So a workaround is to use your names of your data and wrap it in HTML. I replace with `ticktext` the `tickvals` by the same value wrapped with HTML commands.

Since you did not provide your full data i used a public dataset:

```
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Species,  type = 'bar', orientation = "h") %>% 
   layout(yaxis = 
               list(title = "Soil grouping",
                    ticktext = sprintf("<i>%s</i>", levels(factor(iris$Species))),
                    tickvals = levels(factor(iris$Species))
                    )
            )
```

For this i use `sprintf` and wrap the different names of the `iris$Species` with

```
<i></i>
```

this is the HTML - code for "put the letters between in italic".

for bold `<b></b>` can be used.

The output is as expected:

[image: Plot]

This code can now easily be mofidied for your task.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, that was exacly what I needed. Now it works